# Phonegap, JQuery Mobile MVC

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

Is there a way of implementing some sort of MVC file ordering in phonegap+jqm? I have tried to store my files separately and include them in my index.html. It doesn't seem to be adding some js files.

If I have `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Controller.js"></script>`
How should the Controller.js look like? Do I just have my code as

```
errorHandler = function (transaction, error) { 
    // returns true to rollback the transaction
    return true;  
}
```

Or I need to wrap them under some tags? My app does not seem to include my controller.js codes.

In short...how can I best implement MVC kind of layout for ease of management and ensure that my files are being included?

Comment: Did you try including your js code directly in your HTML? If yes, did it work?

Comment: take a look at sencha touch 2 it is completely base on MVC, if you need more info just say it